# File type functions not supported on a live server in PHP

Tags: php, function, file-type

I have application on a live server where I want to check upload file is image or not. In my localhost and other live server following functions are working except one current server.

```
1. mime_content_type($file);
2. $file_type = exec("file $file");
3. $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
   $file_type = $finfo->file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

Some are deprecated, some are disabled due to security reasons. 
Can I have other methods/techniques to get file type which is used to check whether upload file is image or not?

Comment: you have to update your php version on your server. it's very old because `mime_content_type(PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5, PHP 7)`,`exec(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)`,`finfo(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7)` are suppored in corresponding version. So better to get alternatives, update your version now. you will face a lot of problem in future

Comment: @Anant ji, I am using shared hosting online. They refuse to do changes as my wish.

Comment: Oh that dam shared hosting. Check the below answer.Better to switch any other hosting because in near future you will face problem of query execution and etc, because of deprecated libraries in newer version of php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)  to determine if the uploaded file is image or not.

Use it like this,

```
$image_info = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
if ($image_info === FALSE) {
   die("Uploaded file is not an image.");
}
```

> **getimagesize()** function will determine the size of any given image
>   file and return the dimensions along with the file type and a
>   height/width text string to be used inside a normal HTML IMG tag and
>   the correspondent HTTP content type.
> It will return **FALSE** in case of uploaded file is not an image.

Comment: Appreciate it Patel ji. It helped. Now my app little bit more secure.